# Pathfinder and the Rogue's Sneak Attack

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Coming from 3.5 to *Pathfinder* has been interesting in that while it was an update to 3.X, some of the mechanics have changed. An example of this is a PF Rogue's *Sneak Attack*.

In 3.5 a Rogue could not sneak attack an undead creature. It made for some boring battles for the party Rogue in an undead-heavy campaign or session. *Pathfinder* seemingly has changed this under the *Sneak Attack* rules (page 68 PFCR) in that, "The rogue’s attack deals extra damage anytime her target would be denied a Dexterity bonus to AC (whether the target actually has a Dexterity bonus or not), or when the rogue flanks her target." There is no mention in the Pathfinder rules if Rogues are still unable to *Sneak Attack* an undead opponent.

**So, can a Pathfinder Rogue add their *Sneak Attack* damage into their attack on an undead opponent?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, a rogue gets sneak attack against undead in Pathfinder. Undead are not immune to precision damage as they were in 3.5.  One can check the d20pfsrd.com where the rogue section lists an FYI in the sidebar that notes this:

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue#TOC-Sneak-Attack

Comment: Awesome! Do you know, by chance, where in the PFCR this is listed?

Comment: @GPierce I don't know, but it is in the [Conversion Guide PDF](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/v5748btpy89m6) that Paizo has available for free download on their site (download required).

Comment: @CRoss That's good enough for me. I was looking for an official ruling that was a little more legit than the SRD.

Comment: It's also worth nothing that monsters will tell you if they're immune to precision damage. As for finding the rule in a core rulebook it's scattered around, but you can find it in the Bestiary, in the back with the creature type/subtype descriptions.

Comment: Cthos is correct, but in some cases it will be defined under the creature types in the Bestiary as a blanket statement which iirc is in the back or front of the book.